# How to load a pdf from an URL using any server url

Tags: android, pdf, url, webview, pdf-viewer

I am using Webview with toolbar.
The PDF file is present on server,I am attaching this link to webview, but its not working.

I also tried third party libraries like com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView, but its not working.

Please help.

Comment: check if internet permission is asked in manifest.xml file

Comment: yes all permissions are given

Answer (score 2):

Open Your document in webview by using drive url.

```
 WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
 String pdfUrl = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
 webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdfUrl);
```

Comment: it works,Thanks a lot

Comment: Ohh Great. Then please Accept this Answer.